# Could invoking a void statement cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, c11

Imagine this:

```
int X;

X = X;
```

this would be undefined behavior as

> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

[...]

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).

But what about this?

```
int X;

X;
```

would the invokation of `X;` in reference to the quote allow the compiler to cause undefined behavior? Or does this not count as X is "used"?

Comment: You have tagged this question with c99. The answer is different in C 1999 and C 2011. Do you want C 1999 only?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 which is c99. But if the behaving of both is diferent, i would prefered get an answer for both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C 1999, it is not directly an error to use an uninitialized object. (Your quotes from Annex J are not a normative part of the standard; they are just informative.) An uninitialized object with automatic storage duration has an indeterminate value. For some objects, that value may be a trap representation, so using it may result in undefined behavior.

However, for some objects, it is possible to determine that an uninitialized object cannot have a trap value. For example, an `unsigned char` cannot have a trap value, and the exact-width signed integer types defined in `stdint.h` cannot have trap values (because they are two’s complement with no padding bits). For other types, it may be that properties defined by your C implementation cause them not to have trap values. Using an uninitialized `int X` does not have defined behavior in all C 1999 implementations (but does in some), but using an uninitialized `unsigned char X` does.

In C 2011, this text was added in 6.3.2 2: “If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the **register** storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.” Therefore, in C 2011, both `X = X;` and `X;` have undefined behavior.

---

History/background:

The C 2011 change supports a Hewlett-Packard machine which has a special flag for certain registers that indicates whether the register contents are valid or not. The machine can generate an exception if a register is used while its contents are invalid. Hence, if the compiler assigns the `X` of `unsigned char X` to such a register, using the register when it is invalid may cause an exception in the machine even though there is no `unsigned char` trap value.

Comment: A quibble: the *signed* exact-width integer types defined in `<stdint.h>` are two's-complement. `uint32_t` and friends are not.

Comment: What exactly does Appendix J then expresses if the sentences of undefined behaviors in it mentioned aren't normative? I'm kind of confused now.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Updated. Are the exact-width unsigned types supposed to have no padding bits? It does not say there.

Comment: @Zaibis: The informative parts of the standard are supposed to be helpful. Usually they are. E.g., it is nice to have all the undefined behavior or sequence points collected in one place, so you can review them easily. However, when there is a conflict between a normative part of the standard and an informative part, the normative part is authoritative.

Comment: Ah ok, so my quote is true unless a normative part says "It is not true in following cases[...]" did i get that right?

Comment: @Zaibis: The normative part does not need to have specific phrasing. Sometimes things are derived logically from other statements or we have to interpret the standard by figuring out what it makes sense for the authors to have meant.

Comment: I wasn't even fixed on `int` imagine I had chosen float instead, it would be in both (c99 and c11) be UB wouldnt it?

Comment: @Zaibis: Floating-point types may have signaling NaNs, which cause exceptions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: C99 doesn't say that the `uintN_t` types have no padding bits, but 7.18.1.1p3 strongly suggests that that's the intent. C11 makes it explicit. I think it was just an unintentional omission in C99 (and N1256 didn't correct it).

Comment: thats why I'm going to award a bounty to him :)

Answer (score 0):

`X = X;`

The above is undefined behavior. Because `X` is not initialized. The compiler should at least generate a warning about this.

The standard states 6.3.2.1p2:

> > If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

However:

`X;`

The above is similar to:

`1212342413;`

As `X` will evaluate to some expression.

Comment: Thanks so far! But could you also state what the standard says about `X;` As I'm not sure about in how far I could understand the meanign of "use" as in my question quoted from the standard.

Comment: You are quoting *C11* but the question is tagged *c99*

Comment: Why should the compiler generate a warning? The behavior is just not defined, it is not a constraint violation.

Comment: "The compiler should at least generate a warning about this." -- I agree, it *should*, but the Standard doesn't say so.